# Get bitmap attached to fresco drawee?

Tags: android, android-bitmap, fresco

I have a serious problem about how to get the bitmap from the fresco's drawee so I can upload it to the server. I have tried the `draweeView.getDrawable();`but it returns drawable and I don't know what to do next.

Comment: see Drawable#draw and Drawable#setBounds methods

Comment: but I don't understand all these stuff about pipelines and so. I need something simple

Comment: what pipelines? you have Drawable, so read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html javadocs

Comment: I just wanted to get the bitmap from that drawee object. A simple way. But I haven't find any

Comment: so if there is no such thing like `draweeView.getBitmap()` use `draweeView.getDrawable()`